# How to use Controls.PrintDialog，print by PrintVisual() or PrintDocument()

Tags: c#, wpf, printing

How should I set the margins for printing, the paper orientation, and so on. Don't use ShowDialog()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it even if you don't use `ShowDialog()` just set the property's;

```
PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();
printDialog.PrintTicket.PageScalingFactor = 95;
printDialog.PrintTicket.PageOrientation = PageOrientation.Portrait;
printDialog.PrintVisual(customerDG, "Printing the customers list.");
```